# How to set Timed splash screen or image at website startup?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need an image or a splash screen at website startup and it have to close after 5 seconds and redirect to main page.
How to achieve this in asp.net ?

Comment: That's not ASP.net specific. You could use a simple `<meta>` redirect plus a link(so users can skip if the redirect doesn't work or they're impatient). But personally I think such a splash screen is a dumb idea in the first place.

Comment: Actually I need a splash screen or welcome screen for my website, its just like a small window having the contenet of "Welcome Website" and the page have to stays for 5 seconds and then redirect to Main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really ASP.NET specific, you can do this simply with javascript like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = timeout;
    function timeout() {
        window.setTimeout("redirect()", 5000) // Set Timeout, i.e. 5 seconds
    }

    function redirect() {
        window.location = "Home.htm" // Action or page to redirect to
        return
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you.Is it possible to code in the main page itself.
I tried in the main but main page is loading first and later Window.Onload is working .